# What to do when Python gives you this error message: "NameError: name 'divide' is not defined"

Tags: python, nameerror, divide

I try to run the following script using python:

```
age = add (30, 5)
height = subtract (78,4)
weight = multiply(90, 2)
iq = divide(100, 2)
```

And I got an error message:

File "ex21.py", line 22, in 
    iq = divide(100, 2)
NameError: name 'divide' is not defined

I'm utterly lost as 'divide' is a standard math function that python recognizes but it won't on my computer. When I google just the error message, most search results are in a non-English language. I'm wondering if there's something going on with languages.

Your help is much appreciated!!!

---

Revised:

I forgot I had defined 'divide' earlier in the script.  Doh! Thanks for all your help. I'm ever so slowly learning. Thank you so much!!

```
def divide(a,b): 
    return a / b
```

Answer (score 4):

The math functions are accessible from their operators, not built-in functions. Instead, try:

```
age = 30+5
height = 78-4
weight = 90*2
iq = 100/2
```

---

Or, you can define your own functions:

```
def add(*nums):
    return sum(nums)

def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1-num2

def multiply(*nums):
    val = 1
    for i in nums:
        val*=i
    return val

def divide(num1, num2):
    return num1/num2
```

Then your original code will work as expected.

Comment: @LilyYoon-KyoHan, glad to be of help, would you mind accepting this answer by clicking on the green check mark (after 15 minutes)? Thanks!

Comment: You can also import function versions of these operators (`import operator`)

Comment: Fair enough, @NightShadeQueen, but I thought that as the OP was learning python using Learn Python The Hard way, it might be better to show the real math behind the functions.

Answer (score 0):

There have to be functions that you're accessing called `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, and `divide` that you have explicitly defined. Otherwise, use pythons operators +, -, *, /

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is a direct example taken from [Exercise 21](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html) of Learn Python The Hard way.**

There, the author has defined his own `add()`, `subtract()`, `multiply()`, and `divide()` functions as below and then he is using those operators.

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    print "DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b
```

Python provides `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` to perform the appropriate operation.

To perform the desired operation by those particular function names, you would have to define the following functions in your code also. Then you can directly use them.

```
age = add (30, 5)
height = subtract (78,4)
weight = multiply(90, 2)
iq = divide(100, 2)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was am running through the exercises.  I misspelled the name when defining it.  I got confused that I had defined 'divide' as a function... and thought it was something that python just understood. Doh! *facepalm*. Slowly but surely, I'm learning. Thank you!!

Comment: You can define these functions in your code and then call these functions directly.